# Application spring boot not mapping a endpoint

Tags: primavera

When executing a get at the end point "api/products" I get the message that the static resource does not exist

> [Ícone "Verificada pela comunidade"](data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAQAAAAngNWGAAAA/0lEQVR4AYXNMSiEcRyA4cfmGHQbCZIipkuxnJgMStlMNmeyD2dwmc8+sZgxYJd9ErIZFHUyYYD7fkr6l4/rnvmtl7+KitrqV/fq2Y5eLY3Z9S48eRLe7BmVZ9qhTLhQ0algzZWQOVKSsCF8OjAnwbxDTWFDUhPK/jMr1H6HE/IqRky2DyvCefuwItwZzodVoYRiLqMkVCXrwpJ9twZ+sgfDYEFYl8wIWxZ9uFf7zkallxlJh4YrLGsKjZRx7VGHhLqwgFUN45DGdb8MeXGpgB4ABZdeDcpZEY51A+hyLKz4S1W4MQWm3AibWtgWmk6dyISa1pSdyWTOlLXVp0+eL9D/ZPfBTNanAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC)

```
package com.prod.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Product {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private double price;

    // Getters and setters
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}



package com.prod.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.prod.entity.Product;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
}


package com.prod.controllers;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.prod.entity.Product;
import com.prod.repository.ProductRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Product updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product productDetails) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
        product.setName(productDetails.getName());
        product.setPrice(productDetails.getPrice());
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
        productRepository.delete(product);
    }
}

spring.application.name=product
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true


  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.2.4)

2024-03-25T21:22:16.516-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.prod.product.ProductApplication      : Starting ProductApplication using Java 17.0.10 with PID 872 (/home/enzo/Videos/product (1)/product/target/classes started by enzo in /home/enzo/Videos/product (1)/product)
2024-03-25T21:22:16.519-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.prod.product.ProductApplication      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2024-03-25T21:22:16.564-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : Devtools property defaults active! Set 'spring.devtools.add-properties' to 'false' to disable
2024-03-25T21:22:16.564-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] .e.DevToolsPropertyDefaultsPostProcessor : For additional web related logging consider setting the 'logging.level.web' property to 'DEBUG'
2024-03-25T21:22:17.139-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2024-03-25T21:22:17.158-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 10 ms. Found 0 JPA repository interfaces.
2024-03-25T21:22:17.654-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port 8080 (http)
2024-03-25T21:22:17.665-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2024-03-25T21:22:17.665-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.19]
2024-03-25T21:22:17.715-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2024-03-25T21:22:17.716-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1150 ms
2024-03-25T21:22:17.753-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2024-03-25T21:22:17.907-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection conn0: url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb user=ROOT
2024-03-25T21:22:17.908-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2024-03-25T21:22:17.919-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration    : H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:mem:testdb'
2024-03-25T21:22:18.066-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2024-03-25T21:22:18.121-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.4.4.Final
2024-03-25T21:22:18.151-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.h.c.internal.RegionFactoryInitiator    : HHH000026: Second-level cache disabled
2024-03-25T21:22:18.359-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
2024-03-25T21:22:18.403-03:00  WARN 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.orm.deprecation            : HHH90000025: H2Dialect does not need to be specified explicitly using 'hibernate.dialect' (remove the property setting and it will be selected by default)
2024-03-25T21:22:18.656-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000489: No JTA platform available (set 'hibernate.transaction.jta.platform' to enable JTA platform integration)
2024-03-25T21:22:18.660-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2024-03-25T21:22:18.703-03:00  WARN 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2024-03-25T21:22:19.001-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2024-03-25T21:22:19.024-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port 8080 (http) with context path ''
2024-03-25T21:22:19.039-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [  restartedMain] com.prod.product.ProductApplication      : Started ProductApplication in 2.867 seconds (process running for 3.332)
2024-03-25T21:26:47.014-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-25T21:26:47.014-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2024-03-25T21:26:47.015-03:00  INFO 872 --- [product] [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms


Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Mon Mar 25 21:30:42 BRT 2024
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No static resource api/products.
org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.NoResourceFoundException: No static resource api/products.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.java:585)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:564)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:344)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing.
Looks like your com.prod.product.ProductApplication class is under product package hence springboot is not able to scan your controller class. Please can you move com.prod.product.ProductApplication to com.prod.ProductApplication and then build and restart.
I hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: It's already shared in the thread my friend

Answer (score 0):

```
`package com.prod.controllers;`

`import java.util.List;`

`import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;`

`import com.prod.entity.Product;
import com.prod.repository.ProductRepository;`

`@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")
public class ProductController {
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;`

   ` @GetMapping
    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }`

   ` @PostMapping
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }`

   ` @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
    }`
`
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Product updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product productDetails) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
        product.setName(productDetails.getName());
        product.setPrice(productDetails.getPrice());
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }`
`
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Product product = productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Product not found with id " + id));
        productRepository.delete(product);
    }
}
`
`spring.application.name=product
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.enabled=true`
```

Comment: Did you answer your own question? Do you no longer need help from the community?